# Getting error in trying to read applicationContext.xml in Standalone java

Tags: spring

```
ApplicationContext context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
InvGroupDelegate  igcd = (InvGroupDelegate) context.getBean("invGroupDelegate");
```

Giving error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContext.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
```

The appContext file is present in myProject/properties
    And this is also added to 'Src folders in the build path'.

Comment: Have you read the exception?Check whether the file is in the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it. Was an eclipse issue. Closed the project and reopned it. Then cleaned up everything and built once more. Then things were fine.